# Wierd Symfony2 doctrine result behaviour

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Ok my problem is this, I've built a service Building blocks:

```
<?php

namespace Kpr\CentarZdravljaBundle\Extensions;


class Buildingblocks
{
    protected $doctrine;

public function __construct($doctrine)
{
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}

public function articleHmostread($limit)
{
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager ();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a2.title, a2.id, a2.body, a2.path, c.id as cid, c.name FROM KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Category c JOIN c.articles a2 WHERE c.parent !=3 GROUP BY a2.id ORDER BY a2.readCounter DESC'
    );

    $query->setMaxResults($limit);
    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $result;
}

public function testing()
{
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager ();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a2 FROM KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Category c JOIN KprCentarZdravljaBundle:ARTICLE a2 WHERE c.id NOT IN (256) ORDER BY a2.readCounter DESC'
    );
    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $result;
}

public function articleHnewest($limit)
{
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager ();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a2.id, a2.title, a2.path, c.id as cid, c.name FROM KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Category c JOIN c.articles a2 WHERE c.parent !=3 GROUP BY a2.id ORDER BY a2.readCounter DESC'
    );
    $query->setMaxResults($limit);
    $result = $query->getResult();
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}

public function articlesFromCat($id, $limit)
{
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager ();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a2.title, a2.id, c.name FROM KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Category c JOIN c.articles a2  WHERE c.id = ?1 GROUP BY a2.id ORDER BY a2.published DESC'
    )->setParameter(1, $id);
    $query->setMaxResults($limit);
    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $result;
}

public function articleHfeatured($limit)
{
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager ();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a, cat FROM KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Article a JOIN a.categories cat WHERE a.featured = ?1 GROUP BY cat.id ORDER BY a.published DESC'
    )->setParameter(1, 1);
    $query->setMaxResults($limit);
    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $result;
}

public function poiHomepage($limit)
{
    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager ();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p FROM KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Poi p ORDER BY p.published DESC'
    );
    $query->setMaxResults($limit);
    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $result;
}
}
```

Then i registered a global twig global variable:

```
<?php

namespace Kpr\CentarZdravljaBundle\Twig;
use Kpr\CentarZdravljaBundle\Extensions\Buildingblocks;
use Kpr\CentarZdravljaBundle\Helper\Helper;

class MyRenderExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
protected $bblocks;

function __construct(Buildingblocks $bblocks) {
    $this->bblocks = $bblocks;
}

public function getGlobals() {
    return array(
        'bblocks' => $this->bblocks,
        'globalimagepath' => 'uploads/documents/'
    );
}

public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        'pathauto' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'pathautoFilter'),
        'groupname' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'groupnameFilter'),
        'teaser' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'teaserFilter'),
         'htmldecode' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'htmldecodeFilter', array(
            'is_safe' => array('html')
    )));
}
public function pathautoFilter($title)
{
    $helper = new Helper();

    return $helper->pathauto_cleanstring($title);
}
public function groupnameFilter($title)
{
    $helper = new Helper();

    return $helper->groupname($title);
}
public function htmldecodeFilter($string)
{
    return html_entity_decode($string);
}
public function teaserFilter($text, $len = 120)
{
    if(empty($text)) {
       return "";
    }
    if(strlen($text)<$len) {
        return $text;
    }       
    return preg_match("/(.{1,$len})\s./ms", $text, $match)
       ? $match[1] ."..."
       : substr($text, 0, $len)."...";
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'myrender_extension';
}
}

?>
```

so now i can use the bblocks twig variable from any template, here is my index template:

```
{% extends 'KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Main:framework.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
<!-- Banner 970x250px
    <div class="banner billboard"><a href="http://www.centarzdravlja.net"><img src="img/billboard.jpg" width="970" height="250" alt=""></a></div> -->

    <!-- Breadcrumbs -->
    <section id="breadcrumbs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Naslovna</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hrana i zdravlje</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Recepti</a></li>
            <li>Utječe li hrana na pojavu neplodnosti, svečešću pojavu današnjice?</li>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <!-- Main -->
    <main id="main" role="main">

        <!-- Left Column -->
        <section id="main-left">

            <!-- Slides -->
            {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:slider.html.twig" with { articles: bblocks.articleHmostread(5) } %}

            <!-- Articles -->
            <section id="articles">
                <ul>
                    {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig" with { articles: bblocks.articleHnewest(4), flag: 0 } only %}
                </ul>
            </section>

        </section>

        <!-- Center Column -->
        <section id="main-right">

            <!-- Interests -->
            <section id="interests">
                <h3><a href="#">Zanimljivosti</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:poiDefaultBlock.html.twig" with { pois: bblocks.poiHomepage(3) } %}
                </ul>
            </section>

        </section>

        <!-- Right Column -->
        <aside class="clear">

        <!-- Tabs -->
        <ul id="tabs">
            <li><a href="#tab1">Preporučamo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Najčitanije</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Najnovije</a></li>
        </ul>
        <section class="tab-container" id="tab1">
            <ul>
                {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig" with { articles: bblocks.articleHfeatured(4), flag: 2 } %}
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section class="tab-container" id="tab3">
            <ul>
                {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig" with { articles: bblocks.articleHnewest(4), flag: 2 } %}
            </ul>
        </section>

        <!-- Banner 300x250px -->
        <div class="banner rectangle"><a href="http://www.centarzdravlja.net"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/kprcentarzdravlja/img/rectangle.jpg') }}" width="300" height="250" alt=""></a></div>

        <section id="recommendations">
            <h3>Vaše preporuke</h3>
                <ul>


                </ul>
        </section>

        </aside>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <!-- Banner 230x90px  -->
        <div class="banner foursquare left"><a href="http://www.centarzdravlja.net"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/kprcentarzdravlja/img/bar-2.jpg') }}" width="230" height="90" alt=""></a></div>

        <!-- Banner 728x90px -->
        <div class="banner leaderboard right"><a href="http://www.centarzdravlja.net"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/kprcentarzdravlja/img/leaderboard-2.jpg') }}" width="728" height="90" alt=""></a></div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <!-- Featured -->
        <section id="featured">
            <ul>
                {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig" with { articles: bblocks.articleHfeatured(4), flag: 1 } %}
            </ul>
        </section>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <!-- Video -->
        <section id="video" class="section">
            <div class="header blue clear">
                <h3>Video</h3>
                <ul class="blue">
                    <li><a href="#">Najnoviji video sadržaji</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pilates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ostalo</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="corner blue"></span>
            </div>
            <section class="content"></section>
        </section>

        <!-- Healthy Living -->
        <section id="healthy-living" class="section">
            <div class="header orange clear">
                <h3>Zdrav život</h3>
                <ul class="orange">
                    <li><a href="#">Prikaži sve rubrike</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="corner orange"></span>
            </div>
            <section class="content"></section>
        </section>

        <!-- Food & Health -->
        <section id="food-health" class="section">
            <div class="header green clear">
                <h3>Hrana i zdravlje</h3>
                <ul class="green">
                    <li><a href="#">Zdrava prehrana</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Zdravi recepti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vodič za dijete</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="corner green"></span>
            </div>
            <section class="content"></section>
        </section>

        <!-- Trudnica.hr -->
        <section id="pregnancy" class="section">
            <div class="header purple clear">
                <h3>Trudnica.hr</h3>
                <ul class="purple">
                    <li><a href="#">Prije trudnoće</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trudnoća</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Porod</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Moja beba</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Za mame</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="corner purple"></span>
            </div>
            <section class="content"></section>
        </section>

        <section id="strip" class="clear">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.trudnica.hr">Trudnica.hr</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.dijabetes.hr">Dijabetes.hr</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.centarzdravlja.rs">CentarZdravlja.rs</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.vitafest.hr">Vitafest.hr</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.vitashop.hr">Vitashop.hr</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="top">vrh stranice</a>
        </section>

    </main>
 {% endblock %}
```

But there is a problem, when i call the function articleHnewest from the twig

```
{% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig" with { articles: bblocks.articleHnewest(4), flag: 0 } only %}
```

i cant access the keys "c.name" and "c.id as cid" which u can see i get in the BuildingsBlock class dql because somehow my $result variable is transformed to object listing instead of an array when it gets parsed in twig.

I tried var_dump before the result is passed in twig and i get an array but when i debug in twig i get the whole list of variables and my browser breaks because of the overwhelming data.

Here is var_dump inside the BuldingBlocks->articleHnewest(4) class, its an array as u can see:

```
    array(4) {
      [0]=&gt;
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=&gt;
        int(7480)
        ["title"]=&gt;
        string(42) "Što trebate znati o glikemijskom indeksu?"
        ["path"]=&gt;
        string(18) "1365518301_407.jpg"
        ["cid"]=&gt;
        int(266)
        ["name"]=&gt;
        string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
      }
      [1]=&gt;
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=&gt;
        int(7460)
        ["title"]=&gt;
        string(43) "Najbolje i najgore namirnice za alergičare"
        ["path"]=&gt;
        string(18) "1367243414_727.jpg"
        ["cid"]=&gt;
        int(286)
        ["name"]=&gt;
        string(8) "Alergije"
      }
      [2]=&gt;
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=&gt;
        int(7467)
        ["title"]=&gt;
        string(22) "Zašto volimo đumbir?"
        ["path"]=&gt;
        string(18) "1366634351_784.jpg"
        ["cid"]=&gt;
        int(267)
        ["name"]=&gt;
        string(15) "Biljni lijekovi"
      }
      [3]=&gt;
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=&gt;
        int(7459)
        ["title"]=&gt;
        string(25) "Najzdravija pića svijeta"
        ["path"]=&gt;
        string(18) "1367309468_956.jpg"
        ["cid"]=&gt;
        int(274)
        ["name"]=&gt;
        string(15) "Muško zdravlje"
      }
    }
```

Added 24.09.2013:

Ok i just figured out the problem is in this part of the code inside the index.html.twig template:

> {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig" with { articles:bblocks.articleHnewest(4), flag: 0 } only %}

if i transfer the code from the template articleDefaultBlock.html.twig directly inside index.html.twig everything works fine. For some reason including the template from within the template transforms the result lo list of article objects instead of the array with records data that i wanted.

Comment: I hope my problem is understandable, ill explain in more detail if needed, I just beg thee for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i just figured what causes the behavior, when I pass more than one variable to the include twig tag the bblocks.articleHnewest(4) result is transformed to list of object, so when i remove the second variable flag = 0 the result stays in its original state. Why this happens I have no idea, if anybody knows please share.

The solution to this is to set the variables inside twig separately and then pass them all with the include like this:

> {% set newestArt = {articles: bblocks.articleHnewest(4), flag: 0} %}

then instead

> {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig" with { articles: bblocks.articleHnewest(4), flag: 1 }

you put

> {% include "KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig" with newestArt %}

Thanks.